# How to display default value of XML element specified in XSD using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema

You can define a default value for an element or an attribute in an XML-document in the accompanying XSD-document. Below I give the relevant parts from the XSD, XML and XSLT document and the output.

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="testelement" maxOccurs="unbounded"  default="666">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:attribute name="testattribute" type="xs:string" default="xxx" />
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

XML:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd3.xsd">
    <testelement testattribute="aaa">1234</testelement>
    <testelement testattribute="bbb">2345</testelement>
    <testelement testattribute="ccc" />
    <testelement>4567</testelement>
    <testelement testattribute="eee">5678</testelement>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
...
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="testelement">
        <xsl:value-of select="@testattribute" />
        <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br />
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
```

Output:

```
aaa : 1234
bbb : 2345
ccc :
: 4567
eee : 5678
```

This wasn't what I expected. I expected to see 'ccc : 666' on the third line and 'xxx : 4567' on the fourth line. It is easy to specify default values, but is it so hard to get those default values displayed as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865685/display-xsd-defined-default-value-of-attribute-using-xsl)? I thought it worth asking again because the answer is more than 4 years old and much more difficult that specifying the default values.

Comment: Did you try the answer to the previous question?  It *is* complex, but as explained in the answer it's necessary.  And I don't think XSLT has become any more schema-aware.

Comment: No. I am currently studying for a XML exam and the question came up in my mind. What with specifying all the default values without ever mentioning how to display them? If all that was needed was a simple function call I might have added it to my summary, but the complexity of the answer goes way beyond anything mentioned in the course, so I'll just bookmark it in case I ever need it.

Comment: Schema awareness is implementation-dependent. You will get your expected result if you use a *schema-aware* processor such as *Saxon-EE*.

Answer (score 1):

Use following XSL with your XML and XSD

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="testelement">
                    <xsl:variable name="key">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@testattribute">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@testattribute"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <!-- Read default value from Schema -->
                                <xsl:value-of select="document('xsd3.xsd')/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='root']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='testelement']/xs:complexType/xs:simpleContent/xs:extension/xs:attribute[@name='testattribute']/@default"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="value">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="text()">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <!-- Read default value from Schema -->
                                <xsl:value-of select="document('xsd3.xsd')/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='root']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='testelement']/@default"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:value-of select="$key" />
                    <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
                    <br />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
aaa : 1234
bbb : 2345
ccc : 666
xxx : 4567
eee : 5678
```